# Symfony bundle inheritance - How to override/extend a service class

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance

In my `Symfony 2.8` project I use bundle inheritance to override/extend the `FOSUserBundle`: Files with the same path and name in the custom bundle override the original files in the `FOSUserBundle`.

While this works fine with controllers and resources like translations and views, it does not seem to work with service classes.

For example the `FOSUserBundle` uses `Resources\config\util.xml` to define the `fos_user.util.password_updater` service to use the class defined in `Util\PasswordUpdater.php`.

Simply adding a `Util\PasswordUpdater.php` to the inherited bundle does not work. This file is ignored and the bundle still uses the original version.

**Is this an indented behavior for services (since the original service definition still points to the original file), or am I doing something wrong?**

What is the correct way to override/extend services? I found the [information](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#services-configuration), that using a `compiler pass` is the best solution in general. But is this also true/intended when already using bundle inheritance?

Comment: override service with compiler pass is the best solution at all. I think services are beeing loaded much earlier than controller and ressources.

Comment: Have you tried to edit `app/config.service.yml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To overwrite Services you need to create a CompilerPass in your Bundle:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

/**
 * Class OverrideServiceCompilerPass
 * @package Shopmacher\IsaBodyWearBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler
 */
class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

    /**
     * Overwrite project specific services
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $defNewService = $container->getDefinition('service.id.you.want.to.override');
        $defNewService ->setClass('AppBundle\Service\NewService');

    }
}
```

Register it in your Bundle file:

```
class AppBundle extends FOSUserBundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideServiceCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

Then your service file will be loaded. In this file you can either extend original service file and share methods or you create whole new service.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. However the question still is "Is a compiler pass also the right/correct solution when already bundle inheritance is used" I assume the answer is yes, but a confirmation would be great :-)

Answer (score 3):

> I found the information, that using a compiler pass is the best solution in general. But is this also true/intended when already using bundle inheritance?

Yes, Compiler Pass is the most suitable solution to override a service definition. It's standard Symfony DI issue and unrelated with bundle inheritance process.

Also sometimes bundles defines class names in the parameters. In this case you can override service just by set these parameters. But this technique is [not recommended](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html#service-no-class-parameter) by the official best practices and is rarely used today.

Comment: Thank your for the confirmation! I understand that using a parameter to define a service class is not a good idea. However, is there a way to override/replace the arguments that are passed to service in a third party bundle?

Comment: Better way is using of configuration options (or any documented API)   provided by bundle. But obviously not every thing may be configured.
Service overriding techniques (via compiler passes or another) are something like monkey patching and have a common drawbacks. Authors of third-party bundles hardly suppose that any piece of their code will be replaced. They may change something internals in future version and these changes can break your code. So, service overriding is always riskily.